# From where this models.Model coming from in django?

Tags: python, django

As I was creating Django project want to create Models for storing in database later. But in the video the person types :

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Okay, I understand that we are inheriting models class so we can use its properties like CharField, TextField but why we are writing models.Model while inheriting. Can't we just write models? Why he is importing the class method -> Model? Am I missing something in OOPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in Python is object so:

```
from django.db.models import Model

class Post(Model):
    ...
```

is the same as this:

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
```

So about your question, `Can't we just write models?` No, because models is a package which contains a lot of classes and `Model` is one of these. So that you have to use `models.Model` to get the class for `class Post` to inherit from. Like I said above, if you want just simply like Model or something, you have to import the right class which you want to use.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @AshishAgarwal, please mark my answer as the correct one so that other people can reference to it too. And if you think it's useful, give me a vote. :))..

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [Django's GitHub repository](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django).

We can see that [models](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/db/models) is a package and [Model](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9db423d3c525697ad59b14c0dcaaccf2770d062/django/db/models/base.py#L400) is a class written in its [base.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py) module, hence we could do `models.base.Model`, but it is made available in [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9db423d3c525697ad59b14c0dcaaccf2770d062/django/db/models/__init__.py#L46) module, hence we can use it as `models.Model`.